# Ajax render resets selected checkboxes

Tags: jsf, facelets

I have a list of objects with a boolean property. I'm using a list of checkboxes to select/deselect that property for every object in the list. My problem is that after rerendering the form, the already selected checkboxes appear empty. Why is that?

```
<h:form>
    <ui:repeat value="#{bean.employeeList}" var="employee">
        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{employee.selected}">
        <h:outputText value="#{employee.name}" />
        </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
    </ui:repeat>

    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{bean.isDone}">
        <f:ajax event="click" render="@form" />
    </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
</h:form>
```

Comment: What's the scope of the backing bean? And at what point is `employeeList` being populated?

Comment: The bean is ViewScoped and the list is populated in a PostConstruct method @kolossus

Comment: Verify that `@PostConstruct` isn't being called repeatedly?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be. @kolossus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<f:ajax>` processes by default the current component, as in `execute="@this"`. You need to explicitly specify the entire form by `@form` if you intend to process the entire form.

```
<f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" />
```

Note that I removed `event="click"`. This is namely the default already.